# Is there an attribute used to specify which link, within a telegram HTML parse mode reponse, should be the one that is previewed?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am working on a telegram bot written in python. I am sending a message which contains more than one link <a href=""></a>. It seems that the preview within the telegram chat is determined on which ever preview loads first. See example shot below from testing: [Testing multiple links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiaMl.png)

I am a little stumped as the documention does not say anything about multiple links. What it does talk about is disable_web_page_preview which completely stops the preview. The preview does a lot of the work for me capturing the detail pages image of properties so I dont have to. The solution if this is not possible would be to crawl and get the URL of the image and simply include this in the message to the user. For those who want to see what the message looks like see below:
[HTML python response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rSpD.png)